# Watching a javascript namespace variable in the Firebug console

Tags: javascript, position, firebug, mouse, watch

This may be simple, may not. I am trying to track the mouse position in JavaScript and I want to watch the current position using Firebug.

My page has:

```
var mouse_position = {};
mouse_position.x = 0;
mouse_position.y = 0;
```

And then on the mousemove of the main content I update these variables. I know this works but I want to watch it a bit more. Now, in my Firebug console I can add a watch to mouse_position.x and when I add it, it gets the current position. Thats all nice.

However, when I move the mouse around, the console does not update. Is this a limitation, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: place the console logging statement inside the actual event handler to have it update every time the mouse moves

Comment: Firebug does not support live watches

Comment: Laker. I do not want to use console.log as it would create hundreds of entries - too many to keep track of. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Chris and what do you expect to happen when watching? Just to see the values change? If you want that, update something in the DOM with the current value in the mousemove handler instead of `console.log()`ing.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a sensible idea. Thanks Matt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.log(mouse_position.x,mouse_position.y)`

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` prints to the console - it is not the same thing as adding a watch that evaluates its contents; it's just a print.

if you want to fake a "watch", you can update the text of an element every time one of the javascript variables changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/f8N69/1/

```
var mouse_position = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};

var box = document.getElementById('test');

document.onmousemove = function (e) {
    mouse_position.x = e.pageX;
    mouse_position.y = e.pageY;
    box.textContent = 'X: ' + mouse_position.x + ' Y: ' + mouse_position.y;
};
```

it's not as nice as a live watch since you have to touch the code, but it works for debugging purposes.

note: `pageX`, `pageY`, and `textContent` will not work on IE<8